# FabricJS Inspecting the Canvas from UnitTests or Automated Tools

Tags: javascript, protractor, fabricjs, puppeteer

We are using FabricJS and items can be rendered to the canvas when actions are taken in the web app.

i.e. Click a button and an object would appear in the fabric canvas.

What are the best methods to check the canvas has been updated correctly using an Automated e2e test?

We are using Puppeteer and/or Protractor for end to end testing.

Is there a good way to check that the canvas contains all of the expected elements?
Are details of the objects in the canvas available to DevTools in any way?

Regards,

Other sources for this problem with no solution.....

https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/4ltvfe/are_unit_tests_with_a_fabricjs_app_possible/

Here is an example, where Puppeteer can open a FabricJs example page. It is possible to get a screenshot of the whole page, and the dataurl for the canvas. However, it would be better to be able to inspect/follow the canvas state and the objects that it contains together with their locations.

http://fabricjs.com/static_canvas

How would you get the location of any of the planets from the example?

The planets are fabric.Circle objects, but rendered to the canvas. Would there be a way to track or follow them?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false, args:['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('http://fabricjs.com/solar-system');
  await page.waitFor(4000)
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  const dataUrl = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("lower-canvas")[0];
    console.log(canvas);
    return canvas.toDataURL();
  });

  console.log(dataUrl);
  await page.goto(dataUrl);
  await page.waitFor(4000)
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

The solution that we went for was to have a hidden button in the page.

This button would be linked to a function that would query the fabric canvas and add a list of object details to a global variable.

This global variable can be queried allowing the test to locate objects in the fabric canvas. It's clunky, but works.

Would love to hear any other suggestions.

```
async renderAllObjectsToApplicationState() {
    console.log('Adding objects to application info');
    const objs = this._mainCanvas.getObjects().map(ob => ({
        id: ob.id,
        left: ob.oCoords.tl.x,
        top: ob.oCoords.tl.y,
        width: ob.oCoords.br.x - ob.oCoords.tl.x,
        height: ob.oCoords.br.y - ob.oCoords.tl.y,
        visible: ob.visible,
        center: ob.path
            ? this.getCoordCenter(ob.path, this._mainCanvas.getZoom())
            : null,
    }));

    applicationInfo['fabricObjects'] = objs;
}
<button
    id="getFabricObjBtn"
    class="float-right"
    style="display: none;"
    (click)="renderAllObjectsToApplicationState()"
></button>

async function getImageViewerFabricObjects(){
    await page.waitFor(100);
    await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#getFabricObjBtn').click());
    await page.waitFor(250);
    const fabricObjects = await page.evaluate(() => window.applicationInfo.fabricObjects);
    return fabricObjects;
}

const fabricObjects = await getFabricObjects();

const roi = fabricObjects.filter(obj => obj.id==="roi");
```